# Draw text word by word with delays (timed)

Tags: ios, swift

I’m making an ios-app which is a kind of poetry-book. One of the functions I want, is a timed “reading”, so the words in a poem appear with the same timing as when I read it. So I have an array with the words in the poem, paired with the delays.

Now I want to loop through the words, draw number 1 on screeen, wait for the corresponding period, draw word number 2, wait and so on ... My question is if somebody have an elegant way og achieving this - or just a functioning way ;-) It is more difficult than I imagined ...

I use Swift 4. Until now I have drawn the words in an Imageview, but then I only get the final resulting image, and I would also rather not lock the mainthread with the delays. So I think the solution is to use dispatch in some way,  but I’m out of my depth. Anybody?
It would be so very helpfull with code that could demonstrate drawing the words of a text in a view, so the words appeared with timings specified as a list of numbers (milliseconds or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, it uses a reflexive method and animates the showing of words as well as setting the delay to the next word. The `display(poem:)` function does all the work, but here you have the whole test project, just create a `UITextField` and a `UIButton` in the storyboard and link them:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    let poem = [("Test ", 0.6), ("my ", 0.4), ("core ", 1.0), ("just ", 0.6), ("like ", 0.4), ("be", 0.4), ("fore", 0.6)]

    @IBAction func animate(_ sender: Any) {
        display(poem: poem)
    }

    func display(poem: [(word: String, delay: TimeInterval)]) {
        guard let first = poem.first else { return }

        UIView.transition(with: textView,
                          duration: first.delay,
                          options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations: { self.textView.text.append(first.word) },
                          completion: nil)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + first.delay) {
            self.display(poem: Array(poem.dropFirst()))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think there is no really "clean" way of doing this. Here's how I would try it:

```
func showWords(words: [String]) {
    var a: DispatchTime = DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: 0) // the delay in nanoseconds (most precise way)

    for each in words {
        let animationTime = 0.3 // you'll need to find a way to calculate how long it takes for each word to appear
        a = DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: a + (animationTime*1000000000)) // calculate ddispatch time in nanoseconds

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + a, execute: {
            self.writeWord(each)
        })

    }

}
```

What this basically does is that it animates all the words at once but it animates each word with the delay that the words before it need to finish calculating. This is how I made a typewriter effect. However, I had to experience that **older iPhones tend to be a little overwhelmed** because this method blocks the main thread very much.